# Trying to combine 2 tables of data to show a list across multiple queries in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to combine 2 tables of data. However, all of my results are getting stuck in one set of results. I need the results to go across multiple.
Here is what Is happening:
[image: What is Happening]

```php
<?php
    $con = new mysqli("mysql.hostinger.co.uk", "-", "-", "-");            
    $con->set_charset('utf8mb4');
        
    //Retrieve all the data from the Main Data Table
    $result = $con->query("SELECT StreamDayID, WeekColor, DayName, StreamTitle, StreamGame, TIME_FORMAT(StartTime, '%r') AS StartTime, DATE_FORMAT(StreamDate, '%D %b') AS StreamDate FROM `WeekData` WHERE WeekColor='Blue'") or die(mysql_error());

    //Retrieve all the data from the Joiners Table
    $joinresult = $con->query("SELECT JoinID, JoinedBy, StreamID FROM `JoinedBy` INNER JOIN `WeekData` ON StreamID = StreamDayID") or die(mysql_error());

    echo "<div id='blue' class='day'>";
    echo "<h1 class='row'>Blue:</h1>";
        
    //keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        //Print out the contents of each row into a table
            echo "<div id='blue";
            echo $row['StreamDayID'];
            echo "' class='les'>";
                echo "<div class='title'>";
                    echo "<h2>";
                    echo $row['StreamTitle'];
                    echo "</h2>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='detail'>";
                    echo "<h4>Day: ";
                    echo $row['DayName'];
                    echo "</h4>";
                    echo "<h4>Game: ";
                    echo $row['StreamGame'];
                    echo "</h4>";
                    echo "<h4 class='joiners'>Joined By:";
                    while($join = mysqli_fetch_array($joinresult)){
                        echo "<a class='delink' href='https://twitch.tv/";
                        echo $join['JoinedBy'];
                        echo "'>";
                        echo $join['JoinedBy'];
                        echo "</a>";
                    };
                    echo "</h4>";
                    echo "<h4>Start Time: ";
                    echo $row['StartTime'];
                    echo "</h4>";
                    echo "<h4>Stream Date: ";
                    echo $row['StreamDate'];
                    echo "</h4>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
    };
?>
```

Here is What I want to happen:
[image: What I want it to do]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `$joinresult` needs to be defined within the first `while` loop. This will allow you to filter the `JoinedBy` table on the current `StreamID`.

Currently you're returning **every** row in `JoinedBy` as there is no filtering.

To filter by the `StreamID` I would suggest using a prepared statement and setting a filter in the `WHERE` statement:

```php
...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    // initialise the statement
    $stmt = $con->stmt_init();

    $stmt->prepare("SELECT JoinID, JoinedBy, StreamID FROM `JoinedBy` WHERE StreamID = ?");
    // if `StreamDayID` is an integer, change "s" -> "i"
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $row["StreamDayID"]);

    $exec = $stmt->execute();
    if(!$exec){
        // error
        die(mysql_error());
    }

   $joinresult = $stmt->get_result();

    ...

    echo "<h4 class='joiners'>Joined By:";
        while($join = mysqli_fetch_array($joinresult)){
            ...
```

NOTE: You don't have to use a prepared statement in this case as you know the value (i.e. SQL injection unlikely), **BUT** it is good practice to do so.

Comment: Do I need to change anything in my PHP to have this work? I am getting undefined variable errors when adding it directly

Comment: I had to change
"$joinresult = $mysqli->stmt_init();" to "$joinresult = $con->stmt_init();"
in order to see any result however it shows:
Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in /home/u992986858/public_html/StreamSchedule/weekDataBlue.php on line 45
Which is "while($join = mysqli_fetch_array($joinresult)){"

Comment: @KiddabobStamp I've made some adjustments - the main thing missing was the `get_result` part - I must have had the result confused with the statement. See if that works